# How do you calculate the Attack and damage workspace?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, character-sheets

I am relatively new to D&D, and there has been one question about the character sheet of 4th edition. How do you calculate the attack and damage workspace on the character sheet? So far, I've haven't been using it in my games, also, what is it exactly? I've read the players handbook over and over, but I haven't found anything about it?

Comment: @Purple Monkey Yes, I do

Answer (score 4):

The attack and damage workspaces are there for use as a quick reference when you need to know your total attack and damage bonuses for frequently used attacks without constantly having to recalculate it.

You calculate it as you normally would for an attack or damage roll (half level, proficiency, etc.) and write the appropriate numbers in the appropriate boxes.

- The first box (from left to right) is for the total bonus.
- The second is for half your level, rounded down.
- The third is for the ability modifier used by the power you choose to write in. I.E. if you write in a melee basic attack the ability modifier would be strength, a ranged basic attack would be dexterity.
- The forth is for any class bonuses that might apply to the power. So something like the Fighter's *Fighter Weapon Talent* could be written here.
- The fifth is for bonuses to attack or damage you gained from feats.
- The sixth is for enhancement bonuses from magic items.
- The seventh and final is for any other bonuses.

Here's a snapshot of what it might look like for a level 2 druid (you can put in specific names for powers or whatever you like).

[image: Attack and Damage workspace]

It's a handy thing to fill out as it helps combat move a lot faster since you can just quickly glance at your character sheet and the only calculations you'll really have to make are situational things like flanking or bonuses/penalties from (de)buffs. Obviously you'll also have to recalculate a few things whenever you gain a couple of levels, gain new feats, pick up magic items, or what-have-you.

Comment: What ability do you use in the Abil section?

Comment: @ThatlonelyEladrin That should really be another question. In short: whatever you use for attacks. It might be Str for basic melee attacks, Dex for basic ranged attacks and, say, Wis for your cleric powers. Choose which you want to have a quick reference to.